# Murray & Larry stastistics for sample calculation

Tags: statistics, sampling, central-limit-theorem

I'm looking for a way to measure the error of a market research. Lets say we have an universe of ***N*** and we want to survey a sample ***n***, ¿how can I determine the error?

**I'm trying to, using the Central Limit Theorem, demostrate the "**Murray & Larry**" solution**, i.e.

**n = ( N*(Z^2)*p*(1-p) ) / ( (N-1)*(e^2)+(Z^2)*p*(1-p) )**

where:
e = error
Z = normal distribution based on the confidence level
p = homogenous of the variables that determines our sample?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "Murray & Larry", do you mean Murray R. Spiegel and Larry J. Stephens, who wrote *Schaum's Outline of Statistics*?

Comment: Yes! sorry for not naming them correctly. What about the question? :)